# Why are the calculations in my calculator not correct?

Tags: c#, .net

For my C# class, we are required to program a simple calculator that performs basic mathematical operations(add, subtract, multiply, divide).  I followed the professor's video and his program works fine.  The subtract command seems to add a - in front of the result.  The divide command results in something way off.  What am I doing wrong?

Example:

```
123+2 = 125 (as it should)
123 - 2 = -121
124 / 2 = 0.0161290322580645
12.4 * 10 = 124 (correct)
```

Here is my code:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        string operand = "", operation = "", memory = "";
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void btnNum1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            txtOutput.Text += "1";
        }

        private void btnNum2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            txtOutput.Text += "2";
        }

        private void btnNum3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            txtOutput.Text += "3";
        }

        private void btnNum4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            txtOutput.Text += "4";
        }

        private void btnNum5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            txtOutput.Text += "5";
        }

        private void btnNum6_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            txtOutput.Text += "6";
        }

        private void btnNum7_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            txtOutput.Text += "7";
        }

        private void btnNum8_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            txtOutput.Text += "8";
        }

        private void btnNum9_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            txtOutput.Text += "9";
        }

        private void btnNum0_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            txtOutput.Text += "0";
        }

        private void btnDec_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (txtOutput.Text.IndexOf(".") == -1)
            {

                txtOutput.Text += ".";

            }
        }

        private void btnNegPos_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (txtOutput.Text.IndexOf("-") == -1)
            {
                txtOutput.Text = "-" + txtOutput.Text;
            }
            else
            {
                txtOutput.Text = txtOutput.Text.Substring(1, (txtOutput.Text.Length - 1));
            }
        }

        private void execute()
        {
            if (operation == "+")
            {
                operand = Convert.ToString(Convert.ToDouble(txtOutput.Text) + Convert.ToDouble(operand));
            }
            if (operation == "-")
            {
                operand = Convert.ToString(Convert.ToDouble(txtOutput.Text) - Convert.ToDouble(operand));
            }
            if (operation == "*")
            {
                operand = Convert.ToString(Convert.ToDouble(txtOutput.Text) * Convert.ToDouble(operand));
            }
            if (operation == "/")
            {
                operand = Convert.ToString(Convert.ToDouble(txtOutput.Text) / Convert.ToDouble(operand));
            }
        }

        private void btnAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (operand == "")
            {
                operand = txtOutput.Text;
            }
            else
            {
                execute();
            }
            operation = "+";
            txtOutput.Text = "";
        }

        private void btnSubtract_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (operand == "")
            {
                operand = txtOutput.Text;
            }
            else
            {
                execute();
            }
            operation = "-";
            txtOutput.Text = "";
        }

        private void btnMultiply_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (operand == "")
            {
                operand = txtOutput.Text;
            }
            else
            {
                execute();
            }
            operation = "*";
            txtOutput.Text = "";
        }

        private void btnDivide_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (operand == "")
            {
                operand = txtOutput.Text;
            }
            else
            {
                execute();
            }
            operation = "/";
            txtOutput.Text = "";
        }

        private void btnClear_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            txtOutput.Text = "";
            operand = "";
            operation = "";
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void btnEquals_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (operation == "+")
            {
                txtOutput.Text = Convert.ToString(Convert.ToDouble(txtOutput.Text) + Convert.ToDouble(operand));
            }
            if (operation == "-")
            {
                txtOutput.Text = Convert.ToString(Convert.ToDouble(txtOutput.Text) - Convert.ToDouble(operand));
            }
            if (operation == "*")
            {
                txtOutput.Text = Convert.ToString(Convert.ToDouble(txtOutput.Text) * Convert.ToDouble(operand));
            }
            if (operation == "/")
            {
                txtOutput.Text = Convert.ToString(Convert.ToDouble(txtOutput.Text) / Convert.ToDouble(operand));
            }
            operand = "";
            operation = "";
        }

        private void btnBackspace_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            txtOutput.Text = "";
        }
    }
```

Thanks for your time.

Comment: I didn't really bother with the code, but here's a hint: 2 / 124 = 0.0161290322580645

Comment: I think you'd be much better off learning to debug than simply posting the code on StackOverflow and asking what's wrong with it. If you set a breakpoint, it should be clear why the operations are not producing the result you're expecting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're getting the result for 
    2 / 124 = 0.0161290322580645

Invert your dividend and divisor ;)

Comment: Subtraction suffers from the same problem, no doubt.

Answer (score 1):

You are operating on your arguments backward. So in your equals function for division you are dividing the second operator by the first giving you the fraction. In the subtraction you are doing 2 - 123 and getting a negative number so for instance change to

```
 txtOutput.Text = Convert.ToString( Convert.ToDouble(operand) / Convert.ToDouble(txtOutput.Text));
```

Comment: This will give you a compiler error, cannot divide a "double" by a "string". Need to move the `Convert.ToString` outside of the calculation.

Comment: @RonBeyer you are correct sir, I copy / pasted too hastily. I have fixed it.